# Element footer dont down using the bootstrap class when I open the menu in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In mobile mode is having problems when I open the menu because this collides with the buttons to move images of carousel and also with the footer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0275d8;
}
```

já tentei usar   z-index: -1;

```
<div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
      <hr>
          <div id="aviso">  
            <div id= "posicaoaviso">
                <span id="fecharaviso" >&times;</span>
                <center><p><strong>Uso de cookies:</strong> Este site utiliza cookies para ajudar a disponibilizar os respetivos serviços e analisar o tráfego.<br>As informações sobre a sua utilização deste site são partilhadas com terceiros.<br>Ao utilizar este site, concorda que o mesmo utilize cookies.</p></center>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Click [here](http://turismo.adota-me.tk/) to see the website.

Or the problem is in foot or in menu or in carosel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this css:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Source: [Bootstrap example](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples/sticky-footer).

PS: Olá de Portugal :)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147704/elemento-footer-n%C3%A3o-descem-usando-a-class-bootstrap-quando-abro-o-menu-em-modo-m

Comment: It does, i've tested on your website. You just have to have a fixed height footer and update the margin-bottom to that height.

Comment: footer come stranger now

Comment: Set the height of the footer to 120px, which is what it was being calculated by the auto

Comment: You also need to change the margin-bottom of the body (i'm refreshing the website :) )

Comment: seems perfect now. How do you get this value? 120px?

Comment: I used the chrome dev tools to check what the height was when you had it set to auto